# How to preserve home made orange juice

Tags: food-preservation, juice, oranges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep fresh-squeezed fruit juice?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19567/how-to-keep-fresh-squeezed-fruit-juice)

I love orange juice and I make it using blender. Yesterday I made juice of around 50 oranges. At the end of the day I still had around 2 litres of it left in an aluminium (my guess) container. Container was not air tight. I didn't put it in the fridge because temperature is around freezing point in my city these days.

In the morning when I opened the container I saw a an orange foam layer above the real juice. When I tasted the juice it was too bitter in taste. I had to throw it away at the end :(

My questions

- How can I preserve home made orange juice?
- How can avoid foam over orange juice?

Comment: Are you interested in only preserving as much flavor as possible, or are you drinking fresh OJ for the nutritional benefits of fresh squeezed juice? If the latter, I suspect the best preservative method is in the oranges.  IOW, only squeeze as much as you're going to drink immediately.

Comment: Refrigerate for a few days, freeze for longer; that's pretty much always the answer for liquids.

Comment: Also, orange juice is acidic, and acids in general should avoid aluminum containers. Stainless steel (if you need metal), glass, or various platics would be better options.